# SQL query with joins help needed

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables.

**DocumentList**:

```
DocumentID  int 
DocumentDescription varchar(100)    
DocumentName    varchar(100)    
DocumentTypeCode    int 
Archive ud_DefaultBitFalse:bit
```

**DocumentStepLevel**:

```
DocumentStepID  int
DocumentID  int
StepLevelCode   int
```

**DocumentAttachment**:

```
DocumentAttachmentGenID int
DocumentStepID  int 
AttachmentGenID int 
FacilityGenID   int 
Submitted   ud_DefaultBitFalse:bit
```

**Attachment**:

```
AttachmentGenId int 
FileName    varchar(255)    
FileDescription varchar(255)    
UploadDate  ud_DefaultDate:datetime 
DocumentData    varbinary(MAX)  
MimeType    varchar(30) 
Archive ud_DefaultBitFalse:bit  
UpdateBy    int 
UpdateDate  ud_DefaultDate:datetime
```

1. Documentlist table contains a list of documents.
2. DocumentStepLevel is a table that associate documents in DocumentList with a step level. We have six steps right now and each step have some documents associated with it.
3. DocumentAttachment table is junction/relationship table that create relationship between DocumentStepLevel and Attachment table.
4. Attachment table has the actual files data uploaded to the system

**Question:**

I need to write a query that will fetch the following columns.

```
DocumentList.[DocumentDescription] 
DocumentList.[DocumentName]
DocumentStepLevel.[DocumentStepID]
DocumentStepLevel.[StepLevelCode]
DocumentAttachment.[DocumentAttachmentGenID]
DocumentAttachment.[FacilityGenID]
DocumentAttachment.[Submitted]
Attachment.[FileName]
Attachment.[FileDescription]
Attachment.[UploadDate]
```

Query should return data from `DocumentList` table for specific step level. When `DocumentAttachment.[Submitted]` column is set to true it should also return the data from `DocumentAttachment` and `Attachment` tables as well. Otherwise those columns will return nothing.

I tried using left outer join but problem happen when I add Submitted column to query. When I add that column to query it stop returning any data until that flag is set to true.

Comment: Can you show the query you tried to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    documentStepLevel dsl
JOIN    documentList dl
ON      dl.documentId = dsl.documentId
LEFT JOIN
        documentAttachment da
ON      da.documentStepID = dsl.documentStepId
        AND submitted = 1
LEFT JOIN
        attachment a
ON      a.attachmentGenId = da.attachmentGenId
WHERE   dsl.stepLevelCode = @stepLevelCode
```

Comment: That's working exactly as I needed. I was putting the submitted in where clause and obviously it was not working correctly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is it DocumentAttachment you're left outer joining?

Difficult to say for sure without seeing your current query, but I'm guessing you've outer joined to DocumentAttachment and then have something like "where documentattachment.submitted = 1"?

In this case I believe it won't return anything as for rows where documentattachment doesn't exist, submitted is effectively null. So you might need to change your where statement to "`where (documentattachment.submitted = 1 or documentattachment.submitted is null)`"

This also assumes that when DocumentAttachment is populated, submitted by default has a 0 value rather than a null value (otherwise you'll need a different method of ascertaining the absence of a DocumentAttachment)